# How do you add an element to a class (through JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, html

Suppose that I want to add a newly created paragraph (using document.createElement("p")) into an existing div (with class name "container") in one of my html files. Is there a way to do this by calling some methods?

Since there's a *getElementById()* method, I figured I would use a *getElementByClassName()* method too, but that doesn't exist; what exists is *getElement**s**ByClassName()* instead. One way I can get around this is to just change my div to have an id rather than a class name, and use the *getElementById()* to add the paragraph into the div, but I wanted to know if there was some method that I could call that would help me retrieve a class element (rather than the elements within the class itself).

I've tried looking for this online, but what I've found are answers to "how to add class names to elements" instead, which is not what I want to know.

Comment: document.querySelector('.classname');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one element, this will chose first in DOM order:

```js
var p = document.createElement("p");   
p.innerHTML = "p element";                   
document.querySelector(".container").appendChild(p);
```

```html
<div class="container">container</div>
```

For all elements with chosen class:

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('.container')].forEach(el => {
var p = document.createElement("p");   
p.innerHTML = "p element"; 
el.appendChild(p);
})
```

```html
<div class="container">container</div>
<div class="container">container2</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I guess I didn't look well enough.

Comment: I would be careful here.  What happens if you have 2 or 3 divs with that classname

Answer (score 1):

HTML DOM elements' IDs have to be unique within a document - and so asking for an element by Id will return you just one element (or null if there isn't a matching element).

However a class name can be applied to multiple elements, so you would expect to get zero one or more elements when searching by class, hence the getElement**s**ByClassName returns a collection.

So if you have a list of elements with the class name container, and you know your document (hopefully) only contains *one* element with that name, you can pick the first element returned by the getElementsByClassName - e.g. `getElementsByClassName('container')[0]`

Note - getElementsByClassName returns all elements to which the class has been directly applied, for the children of the element on which it is being called. I've interpreted your query as relating to the whole document in the context of your original question.